# Closed form of maximum of reciprocal distances

Tags: calculus

Given two points on the unit circle $e^{ix}$ and $e^{i(x + \omega)}$ where $x$ is real and with a minimum angular distance $\alpha$, i.e., $\omega \in [\alpha,2\pi-\alpha]$. Now given a complex number $\lambda$, I would like to find

$$
m = \max_\omega \left| \frac{1}{e^{ix} - e^{i(x + \omega)}} - \frac{1}{\lambda - e^{i(x + \omega)}} \right|
$$

Possible maxima are for sure at the edges $\omega = \alpha$ and $\omega = 2\pi - \alpha$. How to find the other local maxima?

The context of this question is in numerical eigensolvers where reciprocal distances of possible solutions are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\left| \frac{1}{e^{ix} - e^{i(x + \omega)}} - \frac{1}{\lambda - e^{i(x + \omega)}} \right|{=\left| \frac{e^{ix}}{e^{ix} - e^{i(x + \omega)}} - \frac{e^{ix}}{\lambda - e^{i(x + \omega)}} \right|\\=\left| \frac{1}{1 - e^{i\omega}} - \frac{1}{\lambda e^{-ix} - e^{i\omega}} \right|\\=\left|{\lambda e^{-ix}-1\over (1-e^{i\omega})\cdot ({\lambda e^{-ix} - e^{i\omega}})}\right|}$$then the problem converts to minimizing $$|(1-e^{i\omega})\cdot ({\lambda e^{-ix} - e^{i\omega}})|^2{=(2-2\cos \omega)\cdot \Bigg(1+a^2-2a\cos (\omega-\theta)\Bigg)}$$where$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\lambda e^{-ix}\triangleq a e^{i\theta}\quad\text{(the polar representation)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, this is most helpful. May I edit your notation from $\alpha$ to $a$ to avoid confusion with the minimum angle in my question?

Comment: Your welcome. Sure! Feel free to change whatever needed...